# ISO 8601 Date JS Interpretation Difference - IE/FF versus Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api, isodate

Why do IE/FF and Chrome javascript engines [differ on how to interpret](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) this **Date format** (*YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.fff*) without the timezone designator?

```
new Date("2015-02-18T15:43:57.803").getUTCHours()
```

#### UTC Hours

> **Chrome:** 15
>   
>   **IE11/FF:** 21

I don't understand this - is it because Chrome assumes it's local whereas IE/FF assume it's UTC? This seems like a Chrome bug.

Interestingly - appending a "Z" to the end of the string tells both Chrome and IE/FF that the time is UTC and they can agree. Has anyone else noticed this javascript implementation discrepancy with `Date`?

```
new Date("2015-02-18T15:43:57.803Z").getUTCHours()
```

#### UTC Hours

> **Chrome:** 15
>   
>   **IE11/FF:** 15

Ultimately - this is the result of the [out-of-box serializer for ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization), which I thought used JSON.NET, but now appears to be internal where JSON.NET uses [`IsoDateTimeConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/IsoDateTimeConverter.cs).

Checking `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter` tells me we're using [`JsonMediaTypeFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.jsonmediatypeformatter%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). Is Web API not using JSON.NET serializer out of the box?

This is a boon for Web API people - at least back in ASP.NET MVC we had a consistent date format (*albeit proprietary - **/Date(number of ticks)/***) via the [`JavascriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, there are lots of discrepancies when you omit the time zone. Just don't do it :-) This behaviour will change with ES6 as well.

Comment: Sadly - **ASP.NET Web API** omits the timezone out-of-the-box. How helpful for new adopters - you have to customize it before you can use it. =0 Are people here using [`momentjs`](http://momentjs.com/) on the client or just fixing this on the server via [`JsonNetFormatter`](https://github.com/RickStrahl/AspNetWebApiArticle/blob/master/AspNetWebApi/Code/WebApi/Formatters/JsonNetFormatter.cs)?

Comment: **Web API** is certainly using Newtonsoft.Json (*JSON.NET*) for as its default JSON formatter via `JsonMediaTypeFormatter.SerializerSettings` - [sourced from ASP.NET MVC on github](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/JsonMediaTypeFormatter.cs) via [`BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.cs)

Comment: FWIW - I ran into this issue, chose to append the "Z" and then convert to a real ISO date on client using getTimezoneOffset().

Comment: I just love that /Date(ticks)/ becomes a regular expression.  I worked around that by calling toString() and stripping with...a regex :)
Round and round and round it goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*ES5*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) says that ISO 8601 format dates without a time zone should be treated as local(that interpretation [*has since been revised*](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/87)), but the [*ed. 6 draft*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-date-time-string-format) says to treat them as UTC. Some script engines have implemented ed. 6, some ES5 and the rest neither.

The ed. 6 (and later) aren't consistent with the ISO 8601 specification.

The bottom line is don't use *Date.parse* (or pass strings to the Date constructor), manually parse date strings.

Comment: This ultimately directed me to the ASP.NET workaround - it seems [sometime in 2015 ES6 will be adopted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#ECMAScript_Harmony_.286th_Edition.29), but until then javascript date parsing needs to be explicit about **TimeZone** and not leave it **unspecified**

Answer (score 2):

For us, the crux of this issue is that `DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind` only works if your `DateTime` properties set the `DateTime.DateTimeKind` (*other than `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` - the default*) or better yet - using `DateTimeOffset` which [enforces use of the **TimeZone** specificity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Since we already had `DateTime` class properties, we worked around this for now by assigning the [`JsonSerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializerSettings.cs) from `DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind` (*DateTime default*) to `DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc` in our `Global.asax.cs`. This change essentially appends the "Z" to the end of the `DateTime` - however there is one more step to convert the Local time to UTC.

The second step is to provide the offset by assigning [`IsoDateTimeConverter.DateTimeStyles`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/IsoDateTimeConverter.cs) which JSON.NET [`JsonSerializer`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializer.cs) will pickup from a `SerializerSettings.Converters` and automatically convert from Local time to UTC - much like the out-of-the-box ASP.NET MVC does.

Obviously - there are other options, but this is solution worked for us.

#### Global.asax.cs

```cs
protected void Application_Start() {
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal });
}
```

The [reason this works is because `RoundtripKind` honors DateTime's `DateTimeKind`](https://books.google.com/books?id=EvXX03I5iLYC&pg=PA239&lpg=PA239&dq=AdjustToUniversal%20vs%20roundtripkind&source=bl&ots=jGdh-zuPs0&sig=cfLgFIOjxlSYkFbTlQyMikhLzW4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=13PnVMg8z5HIBJi8gcAK&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBg#v=snippet&q=roundtripkind&f=false) - which is `Unspecified` by default. We want to explicitly convert this to UTC - which `JavaScriptSerializer` used to do for us out of the box for ASP.NET MVC. The [regional offset is provided](https://books.google.com/books?id=EvXX03I5iLYC&pg=PA239&lpg=PA239&dq=AdjustToUniversal%20vs%20roundtripkind&source=bl&ots=jGdh-zuPs0&sig=cfLgFIOjxlSYkFbTlQyMikhLzW4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=13PnVMg8z5HIBJi8gcAK&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBg#v=snippet&q=adjusttouniversal&f=false) by `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` which converts your Local `DateTime` to UTC.